# How to set JSON formatted images to show slider in 3d JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working in 3d JavaScript with canvas rendering images. The images as JSON format to rendering. Now this is working fine with 360 degree transitions, but I want to show the images one by one with slider format. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how to do a slider?  Are you trying to abandon your current 3d format or just incorporate a slider in, somehow?

Comment: could you proved a jsFiddle?

Comment: this is sample of 360 degree rotation.http://www.360slider.com/responsive.html .but my module has more than 10 images is there with json formated.so now i want to show one by one displaying the images in 3d javascript.can any one help me.